# Why does ASP.Net MVC rename my "Fixed" Area to "_Fixed"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I was recently trying to create a new Area called `Fixed` in **Visual Studio 2012** with ASP.Net MVC and it would rename it to `_Fixed`

I could go back and rename it to `Fixed` and it would build without errors - but by default, it would rename it to `_Fixed`.

Why does this happen? I tried searching a bit but could not find an answer.

[image]

[image]

**Update 01:** After Stephen's comment, I tried running this in Visual Studio 2015 and VS2015 did **not** do the renaming. It let the Area be `Fixed`. Hence, this is specific to `Visual Studio 2012` I think.

Also, this does not have anything to do with Resharper as I get the same  behaviour with R# disabled.

Comment: I cannot duplicate this - the area name is `Fixed` not `_Fixed`. Perhaps something to do with ReSharper?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Are you using VS2015? I just tested it in VS2012 with R# disabled and it still edited it to `_Fixed`. However, it worked perfectly in VS2015 - so I am guessing this has to do with VS2012 specifically. I'll update my question accordingly. Thank you for checking this out.

Comment: I tested with VS2013 and VS2014 and it generated `Fixed` (no longer have VS2012 so you could be right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fixed` is [keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) is .net , you can't use [keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) as class names.

The fixed statement prevents the garbage collector from relocating a movable variable. The fixed statement is only permitted in an unsafe context. Fixed can also be used to create fixed size buffers.

The fixed statement sets a pointer to a managed variable and "pins" that variable during the execution of the statement. Without fixed, pointers to movable managed variables would be of little use since garbage collection could relocate the variables unpredictably. The C# compiler only lets you assign a pointer to a managed variable in a fixed statement.

ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx

***Update*** 
It is better not to use any [C# keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) as class, member,property names.

Comment: OP is using capital F `Fixed`, not `fixed`

Comment: So the interesting bit after some investigation is that in VS2012 (specifically), it adds the `_` before any reserved keywords (irrespective of the case). So whether I try to create an area called `Fixed` or `fixed` or `Const` or `const`, VS2012 adds the underscore. However, I can create a `Fixed` area in VS2015 but the IDE refuses to create a `fixed` Area throwing an error that it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: As it turns out, VS2012 does not allow you to create Controllers or Areas or Classes for reserved keywords (irrespective of the case) - as IIS is case insensitive. Hence, I am going ahead and marking this as the answer.